# Getting the full user name from User.Identity in Razor.Pages project when authenticating using Azure AD

Tags: .net-core, web-applications, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication, razor-pages

I am developing my Razor.Pages web application in .Net Core 3.1 and I configured the authentication using my company AD. I can use without any problem the User.Identity.Name to get the user@domain value but I need to get the full name of the person that is logged in so that I can filter some results of a query to an SQL DB based on the user's full name.

I tried googling around but didn't find anything a solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging around I finally managed to create a method that receives the User.Identity.Name of the logged in user and returns the full name.
Bellow is a snippet of the method!

```
    public static string GetFullName(string domainName)
    {
        string fullName = "";
        UserPrincipal principal;

        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, domainName);
        }

        if (principal != null)
            fullName = $"{principal.GivenName} {principal.Surname}";
        else
            fullName = domainName;

        return fullName;
    }
```